# Problems getting Oracle MDA Client to work with Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, edmx, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have previous experience getting MS SQL Server to work with Entity Framework 6, and ASP.NET 4.5.2 Framework. It works great! However, when I try the same thing with the Oracle Managed Data Access Client, I have not been able to get it to work. These are the steps I have been following:

1. Right click on the Models folder and pick Add ADO.NET Entity Data
   Model.
2. Choose model contents: Empty EF Designer model. It creates
   the **Model1.edmx** file.
3. Right click in the design space of the EDMX
   file, choose update model from database.
4. Choose your data connection

[image]

**This is where it fails.** I briefly see this screen of the wizard, but then it disappears and nothing else happens.
[image]

I have tried it several times and always get the same results. I have seen similar posts on Stack Exchange, but they come with answers saying the Microsoft knows about it and will fix it.  I am using Visual Studio 2022, so I thought it would be working by now.